# What does the syntax [*a..b] mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, operators, splat

***NOTE:** mischa's [splat on GitHub](https://github.com/mischa/splat) has lots of cool interactive examples of * in action.*

By googling, I found that one way to iterate over a range of numbers in Ruby (your classic C-style for loop)

```
for (i = first; i <= last; i++) {
  whatever(i);
}
```

is to do something like this

```
[*first..last].each do |i|
  whatever i
end
```

But what exactly is going on with that `[*first..last]` syntax? I played around with `irb` and I see this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > 0..5
 => 0..5 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > [0..5]
 => [0..5] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > [*0..5]
 => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > *0..5
SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected tDOT2, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
*0..5
    ^
```

Everything I've read online discusses the unary asterisk as being useful for expanding and collapsing arguments passed to a method, useful for variable length argument lists

```
def foo(*bar)
  bar 
end

foo 'tater' # => ["tater"]
foo 'tater', 'tot' # => ["tater", "tot"]
```

and I get that, but I don't see how it applies to the expansion being done in my block example above.

To be clear, I know that The Ruby Way is to iterate over an array or collection, not to use the array length and iterate with an integer index. However, in this example, I really am dealing with a list of integers. :)

Comment: My whole approach may be wrong. I should probably just be doing `(first..last).each ...`, but I'd still like to know what's going on there. :)

Comment: Try also: `x=*0..5;p x` and `a=[1,2,3];b=[4,5,6];c=[*a,*b];p c` (Ruby 1.9+)

Comment: You can also iterate using `first.upto(last){ |i| ... }` or `first.step(last){ |i| ... }` (where the latter method allows you to step by increments other than 1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
[*1..10]
```

is the same thing as

```
(1..10).to_a # call the "to array" method
```

Instances of the `Array` class you have created implement `Enumerable` so your loop works. On classes that define a `to_a` method, you can use the *splat operator* syntax with brackets. Splat does a lot more than just call `#to_a` though, and would be worth a Google search on its own.

Now, in your case, the `Range` class itself is *already* an `Enumerable` so you could just do:

```
(first..last).each do |v| 
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It is called a splat operator. If you use it within certain positions like an argument position or an array, it will expand into its elements:

```
a = [1]
[*a, 3] # => [1, 3]
b = [1, 2]
[*b, 3] # => [1, 2, 3]
```

You can't use it bare or in ranges:

```
*a..3 # => error.
(*a..3) # => error.
```

When you have something that is not an array, it returns itself:

```
a = 1
[*a, 3] # => [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

`[first..last]` is an array containing only 1 range object. `[*first..last]` is an array containing the elements of that range having been sent in as an argument list. `*` works in the context of an argument list.